# How can I manually add italics or underlines to code listings using minted?

Tags: listings, minted

I'm a new user of `minted`, and I have a LaTeX fragment that looks like this:

```
\begin{minted}{python}
`s` = input(`prompt`)
\end{minted}
```

I was previously using the `listings` package:

```
\begin{lstlisting}
`s` = input(`prompt`)
\end{lstlisting}
```

In that package (with appropriate settings), the effect of the single back-quotes was to italicize the code between them, as follows:
[image]

At least using the default settings, this doesn't work in `minted`. Is it possible to achieve the same effect using single-character delimiters? If not, what would be the simplest command to use instead?

The purpose is to distinguish between actual code and placeholder arguments or variables.

EDIT: In addition, I would like to be able to underline snippets of code within longer lines, so answers that address both needs (underlining and italicizing) would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Since posting the above, I found the `escapeinside` option, which allows the following:

```
\begin{minted}[escapeinside=||]{python}
|\emph{s}| = input(|\emph{prompt}|)
\end{minted}
```

This sort of works, but it appears to override the color assigned by minted, and it requires much messier code than I would like.

In short, a solution, but not as nice as I'd like.  Also, while it works in the vast majority of case, it occasionally fails for reasons I don't understand:

[image]